# How to remove the topper part of an abbreviations page

Tags: acronyms, acro

I just want the bottom part of my abbreviation page. I am using acro. How can I remove the upper part?

Here is my latex code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{usa}{
  short=USA,
  long=United States of America,
}
\DeclareAcronym{eu}{
  short=EU,
  long=European Union,
}
\DeclareAcronym{ussr}{
  short=USSR,
  long=Union of Soviet Socialist Republics,
}

\begin{document}

\ac{usa}, \ac{usa}

\ac{eu}, \ac{eu}

\ac{ussr}, \ac{ussr}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if there is a simple way to print all acronyms with the `acro` package, I have just tried with `\ac{*}`. If you want the acronyms to be printed at the end without using them in your main text body, you could convert your code to use `\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}` then you can just `\glsaddall`. If you're looking for a strictly `acro` solution then hopefully someone else can help!

Comment: other packages are also fine to me. I just came across acro.

Comment: It's all mentioned in the manual: `\acuse{foo, bar, baz,...}` or `\acuseall`.

Comment: @cgnieder yeah that works too, I didn't know about that command, thanks for sharing! I have mentioned it in my answer but based it on using the `glossaries` package, you could post that as an answer too for completeness if you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer with a `glossaries` package answer too as I find it more versatile then `acro` and your comment said you were open to alternatives, @cgnieder is correct in saying `\acuseall` does as you require:

[image]

With `glossaries` it looks likes this:

[image]

With this code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}                    % Just for text
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

% \newacronym{cite name}{abbreviation}{long name}
\newacronym{usa}{USA}{United States of America}
\newacronym{eu}{EU}{European Union}
\newacronym{ussr}{USSR}{Union of Soviet Socialist Republics}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\lipsum[1]

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```